# Impact of SQL server express on battery life of tablet

Tags: wpf, windows-8.1, sql-server-express, tablet

We are developing a disconnected app for some of our tablet users (Windows 8.1) who do field work. We are a WPF shop for internal apps and my design is to use WPF and a SQL server express database that we can then synchronize when a connection is available.
An objection has been raised to this that running SQL server express could affect battery life. Google has let me down here. I am unable to come up with any specs on how running Express may affect battery life. I suppose I could shut the service down and restart it when the app opens and closes, but we will probably be building more of these apps for the tablets and i would prefer to leave it running. battery life is a bit of an issue for our users.

Is there any info out there about how many minutes per day of battery life we can expect to loose just by having SQL express running in the background? My assumption is that it is minimal, please confirm. Are there ways (settings) to minimize its effect?

Comment: To be honest its not just about sql express... running wpf exacts a toll on resources.  SQL Express is just another service running in the background.  If the laptops/tablets are not application heavy then battery life should be close to what the manufactures specs call for.  You could always go to a different method of data storage.